# Cannot retrieve localStorage values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a website written mostly in PHP.
The games (javascript) are on .html pages. 
Users:
login > go to home screen > go to game > return home to see results

I am using localStorage.setItem to store the user's score from the game. 
And then localStorage.getItem to display their score on the next page.

The funny thing I can't seem to figure out is...
If a user does the follow path:
login -> home -> game -> results

The values stored in localStorage from the game are null.
However, if the user plays the game twice, i.e.:

login -> home -> game -> results -> home -> game (now results will display)

I should add the game folder is in public/games/game_name/index.html
and all of the other .php pages are in public/

Comment: I think somewhere data was re-writes.

Comment: The information is not sufficient, provide code that set/get local storage in each of these pages. [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @sabithpocker ok editing...